# NSNotification.Name.NSExtensionHostWillEnterForeground does not work

Tags: ios, xcode, notificationcenter, addobserver

I can use NSNotification in last version of Xcode 11.1.
I can trying to update fields values with a my function *refreshFields()* after returning to the app from background.
My code compiles successfully, but function *applicationWillEnterForeground()* never calling.
Where is the mistake?

```
@objc func applicationWillEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification) {
    refreshFields()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear( animated)
    let app = UIApplication.shared
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.applicationWillEnterForeground(notification:)), name: NSExtensionHostWillEnterForeground, object: app)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution.
The mistake in name of Notification. 
It must be: ***UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification***

```
@objc func applicationWillEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification) {
    refreshFields()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear( animated)
    let app = UIApplication.shared
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.applicationWillEnterForeground(notification:)), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: app)
}
```